# How to insert some record in Sql?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, record, insert-update

i'm want insert some record in sql server. i try query but insert all record and value duplicate.

**i need don't duplicate value and insert some record.**

**Table filesTA**

```
runNo   cDate           cIn         cOut    
00001   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:21:00.000 2012-10-09 20:34:00.000 
00005   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:36:00.000 2012-10-09 17:04:00.000 
00006   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:55:00.000 2012-10-09 20:34:00.000 
00007   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:50:00.000 2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 
00008   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:56:00.000 2012-10-09 20:35:00.000 
00009   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:57:00.000 2012-10-09 20:32:00.000 
00010   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:58:00.000 2012-10-09 19:03:00.000
```

**this code Stored Procedure**

```
SELECT 
     em.empNo,
     ISNULL(tf.cDate, '2012-10-09'),
     tf.cIn,tf.cOut
FROM 
     filesTA tf Full Outer join 
     Emp em On tf.runNo = em.empNo AND tf.cDate = '2012-10-09'
```

**result from code Stored Procedure (On Datagridview display)**

```
empNo   cDate           cIn         cOut
00001   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:21:00.000 2012-10-09 20:34:00.000
00002   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL
00003   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL
00004   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 NULL                    NULL
00005   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:36:00.000 2012-10-09 17:04:00.000
00006   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:55:00.000 2012-10-09 20:34:00.000
00007   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:50:00.000 2012-10-09 00:00:00.000
00008   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:56:00.000 2012-10-09 20:35:00.000
00009   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:57:00.000 2012-10-09 20:32:00.000
00010   2012-10-09 00:00:00.000 2012-10-09 07:58:00.000 2012-10-09 19:03:00.000
```

result from code Stored Procedure. it's not insert to sql. But show display on datagridview.

next Step. i need insert record '00002','00003','00003' **or cIn and cOut = null**
but i try insert that's all record and duplicate value.

**this code new.**

```
    Insert INTO 
    filesTA (runNo,cDate,cIn,cOut)
    VALUES 
   (SELECT 
        em.empNo,
        ISNULL(tf.cDate, '2012-10-09'),
        tf.cIn,tf.cOut
    FROM 
        filesTA tf Full Outer join Emp em 
        On tf.runNo = em.empNo AND tf.cDate = '2012-10-09')
```

i need result from code Stored Procedure (On Datagridview display)

Thanks you for your time. :)

Comment: to help people who wants to help you you can prepare http://sqlfiddle.com/ test case and then post it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're getting your duplicates because of either 1) `full outer join` or because you're not using `distinct` when doing your select (you have multiple rows, so will have multiple values).  `full outer join` isn't what you're wanting, I don't think: you're wanting `inner join`.